# UIScrollView does not receive touch events immediately after appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a drawing app where I load an image into a UIImageView and use touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded to draw simple lines. I moved by UIImageView into a UIScrollView to allow the user to zoom in on the drawing. Now, after loading the image, if the user tries to start drawing immediately (within a couple of seconds of the image becoming visible), touchesBegan does not fire. If the user waits 2 or 3 seconds to begin drawing, all works as expected.

I have tried setting `delaysContentTouches=NO` with no effect. I have also implemented `touchesShouldBegin:` but this method is only called when touchesBegan is called (and the drawing works properly). Other solutions I have seen (such as ensuring user interaction is enabled and using hitTest to make sure the hit occurs in the view I expect) don't seem to apply in my case since everything works as expected after 2-3 seconds. Are there any other timing issues I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
```

If you have any kind of gestures, you need to use this possibly:

```
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false;
```

Comment: I've had this problem with Sprite Kit when trying to select the right object, but in this case. you're trying to draw right after the image is being moved. You will need to find a work around. You're only going to have timing issues if you're actually using multiple threads. Provide some code, then maybe I can figure something out.